# In Powershell how can I remove the first x number of characters from Get-ADUser results?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have a list of results from Get-ADUser giving me all users in an OU. The format of the output username is '-prefix-username'. I need to remove the 7 character '-prefix-' and then conduct another Get-ADUser lookup against the remaining 'username' portions. The issue I'm finding is that if I run just the second Get-ADUser lookup where I set $User as just one specific '-prefix-username' it works fine but when I try to process a list I either get an error where there seems to be space after the trimmed username (txt format list - Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'user      ' under:) or the username includes a " that I can't remove from the end of the username (csv format list - Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'user"').

So far I have:

```
get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=SomeOU' -SearchScope 2 | 
Select SAMAccountName | 
Out-File C:\Temp\UserList.txt

$UserList = (Get-Content C:\Temp\UserList.txt)

$StandardUsers = ForEach($User in $UserList) {
   
    Write-Host "Now checking $User"
    Get-ADUser $User.Substring(7) -Properties * | 
    Select-object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, Mail, Manager,EmployeeID    
    }
    $StandardUsers | Out-File -FilePath C:\Temp\StandardUserList.txt
```

Comment: `Get-ADUser ($User -replace  '-prefix-' -replace "\s")` will remove the prefix and any other space, if you need further help, show example of the problematic user names

Comment: It is not clear what you expect to do. Why performing a second `Get-ADUser` with the prefix removed? Do you attempt to search another user account that is "linked" to the first user retrieved ? If this is not the case, then @Theo answer is right.

Comment: Thanks very much that work perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

First thing to mention is that if you create the list using `Select -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName`, you would only get SamAccountnames in the file.

Having said that, why bother with an 'in-between' file at all and simply do:

```
# By default, Get-ADUser returns these properties:
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
# Only ask for properties that are not already in this list.
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=SomeOU' -SearchScope 2 -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Manager, EmployeeId |
    Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, EmailAddress, Manager,EmployeeID |  
    Set-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\StandardUserList.txt'
```

Comment: It's because I need to change the SAMAccountNAme from the initial lookup so that I can lookup a different SAMAccountName, rather than do a direct lookup of the original SAMAccountName

Comment: @Ursa201 Please can you elaborate on that by giving some examples? What is in the 'original SamAccountName' that needs to be changed so you can use that to find another user?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely having issues with saving it to a file (where it gets formatted) and then reading it back in. The formatting could be adding `"` and reading a newline (which you think is a space) character. If you really need to save it then do the following (else just hook up the pipelines):

```
$userList = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=SomeOU' -SearchScope 2 | 
  Select-Object SAMAccountName
$userList | 
  Out-File C:\Temp\UserList.txt

$standardUsers = $userList |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName -PipelineVariable user |
  ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Now checking $user"
    $userWithoutPrefix = ($user -Replace '^-prefix-','') -Replace '(\w|\n)$','' # to use a more advanced version of the suggestion by @Avshalom
    Get-ADUser $userWithoutPrefix -Properties * | Write-Output
  } | 
  Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, Mail, Manager, EmployeeID

$standardUsers | Out-File -FilePath C:\Temp\StandardUserList.txt
```